# How to construct a google like search interface to a Solr service using Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember, and trying to implement a Google-like search interface to a Solr API. i.e. I would like for the results to update automatically on the page as you type.

My first thought was to create a reusable TextSearch CollectionView, with two child views SearchInput, and SearchResults.

Typing into the SearchInput would trigger an event, the event would be caught by the TextSearch CollectionView, which would update the SearchResult child element.

I got the events generated ok, but the TextSearch ContainerView is not able to intercept the event using either actions, functions, or event manager. I can, however, intercept the event in the IndexController for some reason, but I need to have it handled in a reusable TextSearch CollectionView instead (I think).

Finally, I am not able to update the view in the SearchResults (when I try handling the event in the IndexController), and the SearchResult model is not firing on page load.

I'm quite new at Ember, so I'm sure I'm doing something silly here. It's been a bit of a long road to get to this point.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Pastebin:
http://jsbin.com/ezomOkO/3/edit

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{view App.TextSearchView }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="textSearch">
  {{view App.SearchInputView }}
  {{view App.SearchResultsView }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="searchInput">
  {{input type="text" value=query size="50"}}
</script>  

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="searchResults" >
  <ul>
    {{#each concept}}
      <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{else}}
      Sorry, nobody is here. 
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Snomed Search'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("index", {path: "/"});
});

// INDEX
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
});

//TEXT SEARCH
App.TextSearchView = Ember.View.extend({
  actions:{
    search: function(search) {
      this.get('controllers.searchResults').set('model', App.TextSearch.find(search));
      return false;
    }
  },
  needs: "searchResults",
  templateName: 'textSearch'
});

// SEARCH INPUT
App.SearchInputController  = Ember.Controller.extend({  
  query: 'Family'
});

App.SearchInputView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'searchInput',
  keyUp: function(evt) {
    this.get('controller').send('search', this.get('controller.query'));
  }
});

// SEARCH RESULTS
App.SearchResultsController  = Ember.Controller.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.TextSearch.find('Family');
  },
  afterModel: function(posts, transitions){
    alert('model');
  },
  isPublic: true
});

App.SearchResultsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'searchResults'
});


App.SearchResults = Ember.Object.extend({
  total: 0,
  start: 0,
  concepts: Ember.A()
});

App.Concept = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  title: null,
  active: null,
  effectiveTime: null
});

App.TextSearch = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.TextSearch.reopenClass({
  find: function(searchString){
    return Ember.Deferred.promise(function(p) {
      p.resolve($.getJSON("http://solr.sparklingideas.co.uk/solr/concept/select?q=title:" + searchString + "&wt=json&indent=true")
        .then(function(solr) {
            var returned = App.SearchResults.create();
            returned.total = solr.response.numFound;
            returned.start = solr.response.start;
            solr.response.docs.forEach(function (doc) {
              var concept = App.Concept.create();
              concept.id = doc.id;
              concept.title = doc.title;
              concept.active = doc.active;
              concept.effectiveTime= doc.effectiveTime;
              returned.concepts.push(concept);
            });
            return returned;
        }) //then
      );//resolve
    });//deferred promise
  }//find
});//reopen
```

### Update

Many thanks for your help, Jeremy, that was all the information I needed. Brilliant.

Here are some of the lessons learned:

1. You have to wait for a JSON promise to resolve before using the results, like this:

   ```
   search: function(search) {
     var results = App.TextSearch.find(search);
     var _this = this;
     // results is a jquery promise, wait for it to resolve
     // Ember can't resolve it automatically
     results.then(function(results){
       _this.get('controllers.searchResults').set('model', results);
     });
     return false;
   }
   ```
2. I was not aware of the difference between view, render, and controller (Its not all that well documented, but a google search will tell you). But how do these relate to the 'partial' helper? Not sure.
3. By adding '&json.wrf=?' to the end of a Solr URL, you can avoid the call being blocked in your browser because of XSS security.
4. I got very confused by the ember docuementation as to how to reference the model from a view. This is the correct way (for this example):

   ```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="searchResults" >
     Total : {{model.total}}
     <ul>
       {{#each model.concepts}}
         <li>{{title}}</li>
       {{else}}
         Sorry, nobody is here. 
       {{/each}}
     </ul>
   </script>
   ```
5. My events were not getting caught in the view controllers, because by using {{view}} helper in the template, there are no controllers(!). Use {{render}} helpers instead.

Just one minor correction to a comment in the proposed solution, for future readers:

```
    App.SearchResultsController  = Ember.Controller.extend({
      // This controller could be removed.
      // Ember will auto generate one for you.
    });
```

Actually, removing this controller causes a Javascript error:

```
Assertion failed: <App.TextSearchController:ember242> needs controller:searchResults but it does not exist
```

because of the needs attribute of the SearchInputController. In the final example, though, I ended up removing the dependency on the searchResults from the input controller instead.

I believe Ember now requires event handlers to be wrapped in the 'actions: {}' parameter, like this:

```
    actions:{
      search: function(search) {
        var results = App.TextSearchController.find(search);
        var _this = this;
        // results is a jquery promise, wait for it to resolve
        // Ember can't resolve it automatically
        results.then(function(results){
          _this.get('controllers.searchResults').set('model', results);
        });
        return false;
      }
    }
```

*PLEASE NOTE:*

JSBin uses EmbeJS RC6, which is a couple of months old. The above change to wrapping event handlers in an 'action' attribute was seemingly introduced after RC6. IF you are using the latest version of Ember (as you should), THEN your (eventing) code will NOT work in JSBin (using the default Ember library). However, if you DON'T use the action wrapper, THEN your code will not work in your browser. Hum... See github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases

In the JSBin example below, I have therefore removed the 'action:' tag from the event handler, so the app will run.

I also made some small design changes:

- I moved the search event handler from the InputController to the
  containing TextSearchController instead, in order to decouple the
  InputController from the SearchResultsController.
- I also removed the
  initial search on page load, so the user starts with a blank slate.
- Finally, I removed the TextSearch Object, and moved the solr
  integration to the TextSearchController instead.

The final version can be found here:
http://jsbin.com/ezExeCI/1/

Your help is greatly appreciated, Jeremy. I couldn't have done it without you. I'll make sure to pay it forward.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're fairly close in your jsbin, and there are two different ways you could approach the fix.

1. Don't use Views directly, use `render` instead.  Generally you don't want to be instantiating views directly.  When you do so, you don't end up with distinct controllers for each view.  Instead each of your views ends up being connected to the main controller where your rendering starts.  In this case `App.IndexController`.  Better than instantiating views directly with `{{view App.TextSearchView}}` is to use `{{render "textSearch"}}`.  Using `render` means that you get controllers backing each of your distinct views/templates.  If you put the `search` method on `App.SearchInputController` then it will get called.

   Here's a `render` based jsbin : http://jsbin.com/aNowEZO/1/edit
2. Continue to use views.  If you really want to continue to instantiate views directly, just be aware that the controller that is in context is your `App.IndexController`.  In that case your `search` method, and your `query` property both need to live on the `App.IndexController`, and you don't need `App.SearchInputController` and `App.SearchResultsController` since they never get used by Ember.

   Here's a jsbin showing that : http://jsbin.com/EMexuXU/1/edit

Also worth noting is that `model` and `afterModel` are callbacks called on a `Route`, not a `Controller`.

Finally, you'll see that that the search doesn't actually work in the "Continue to use views" jsbin because of cross domain restrictions.  You'll see this error : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://solr.sparklingideas.co.uk/solr/concept/select?q=title:Familys&wt=json&indent=true. Origin http://run.jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`  To fix that you'll either need to serve your app from 'solr.sparklingideas.co.uk', or you'll need to get your Solr server to send appropriate CORS headers.

Luckily Solr can send jsonp, which is not constrained by cross domain restrictions, by adding `&json.wrf=?` to the URL.  jQuery automatically handles the jsonp response for you.  The "Don't use Views" jsbin contains the jsonp fix and a few other random bits that I had to tweak to get things working.  (http://jsbin.com/aNowEZO/1/edit)